# Passing state setter to multiple components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code;

```
export default () => {
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(GameStateMap.MAINMENU);
    const getGameComponent = useMemo(() => {
        switch (gameState) {
            case "MainMenu":
                return <MainMenu />
            case "Game":
                return <Game />
            case "GameOver":
                return <GameOver />
            default:
                throw new Error("Invalid Component");
        }
    })
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            {getGameComponent}
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

I intend for `MainMenu`, `Game` and `GameOver` to all have access to `setGameState`. Is my best option simply to pass setGameState to each in turn, or is there a more conventional alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you **invoke** (`<MainMenu/>`) and then assign (`getGameComponent =`)

You should **assign** and then **invoke**, then you can pass a prop to it:

```
export default () => {
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(GameState.MAINMENU);

  // Component should be Uppercased
  const GameComponent = useMemo(() => {
    switch (gameState) {
      case "MainMenu":
        return MainMenu;
        break;
      case "Game":
        return Game;
        break;
      case "GameOver":
        return GameOver;
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error("Invalid Component");
    }
  });
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <GameComponent onGameStateChange={setGameState} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

A better re-write of this component (opinioned) could be:

```
const GAME_STATE = {
  MainMenu: MainMenu,
  Game: Game,
  GameOver: GameOver,
};

export default () => {
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(GameState.MAINMENU);

  const GameComponent = GAME_STATE[gameState];

  // Better show error in the UI and not a runtime exception.
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {GameComponent ? (
        <GameComponent onGameStateChange={setGameState} />
      ) : (
        `No such game state`
      )}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Perfect, great answer and well explained, thank you.

Comment: @Tomppa thanks, feel free upvote and accepting the answer

Comment: Of course, will do as soon as the delay wears off :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two schools of thought on this one. The first is called prop drilling, this is what you proposed doing in your original question. The second is using React Context. I have used both in the past. Both have benifits and drawbacks. I prefer to use context. However, that is my opinion.

Here is an article explaining the diff between the two. 
https://medium.com/@jtonti/context-vs-prop-drilling-in-react-aa88fff7cd44

as for how to do either See below.

```
    // in App.js or your main page
    export default () => {
        const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(GameStateMap.MAINMENU);
        const getGameComponent = useMemo(() => {
            switch (gameState) {
                case "MainMenu":
                    return <MainMenu setGameState={setGameState} />
                case "Game":
                    return <Game setGameState={setGameState}  />
                case "GameOver":
                    return <GameOver setGameState={setGameState}  />
                default:
                    throw new Error("Invalid Component");
            }
        })
        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {getGameComponent}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }

    // in MainMenu
    ...
    const {setGameState} = props // or this.props if using classes
    // code to use setGameState
    ...
```

for using context

```
// in app.js
const AppContext = React.CreateContext();
export default () => {
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(GameStateMap.MAINMENU);
    const getGameComponent = useMemo(() => {
        switch (gameState) {
            case "MainMenu":
                return <MainMenu />
            case "Game":
                return <Game />
            case "GameOver":
                return <GameOver />
            default:
                throw new Error("Invalid Component");
        }
    })
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <AppContext.Provider value={{setGameState}}>
            {getGameComponent}
            </AppContext.Provider>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

// in MainMenu
... 
const {setGameState} = useContext(AppContext);
...
```